# PHP: Load Lectora SCORM Module

Tags: php, module, scorm

How would I go about loading a module created with Lectora, with PHP? I can't seem to find any good tutorials. Using an LMS like Moodle is out the question unfortunately. The module is in the form of a .zip file.

Comment: It sounds like you do not have an LMS so are you looking to publish a course for a LMS or just use Lectora's internet publish option and host the course on a website?

Comment: @shooksm: The latter of the two. We will be given a module, and need to present it online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your response in the comments and assuming the instructional designer creating the course publishes the course using the HTML option than the zip file will just contain standard html, JavaScript and image files. You can just use standard tools to unzip the package and FTP or copy the files to the web server and do not need any special tools or scripts on the server side to unpackage the course. A published Lectora HTML course will have an index.html at the root of the package that you will want to link to when launching the course. Hope this helps.